# Access an item in ListProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, listproperty

I have a `Model` like below

```
class XXX(db.Model):
    f_list = db.ListProperty(int,indexed=True) #Store 50000 numbers
```

How to access the 3rd item in f_list?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with what you have? What do you mean *"won't read the full `f_list`"*? What is the output, and what were you expecting?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want more effective method to get the third_item without having to load the full 50000 numbers in f_list

Comment: @jonrsharpe My problem is: How to get the third_item in f_list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a standard list indexing operation to access the 3rd item in the list

```
some_obj.f_list[2]
```

However the entire entity will be loaded into memory when you fetch an instance of XXX

There is no way around it with the model you have.

Even a projection query will return the entire list.

The only possibility would be to start creating multiple sub entities.